# C# - Disable automatic UTC offset for dates JSON

Tags: c#, restsharp

`JSON` that I get from the application has date field in format like

```
"Date":"2016-04-22T00:00:00.000+0000"
```

And when it gets deserialized by the RestSharp, the date becomes equal to

```
"04/22/2016 03:00:00"
```

After brief investigation, I understood that RestSharp automatically applies UTC offset for the parsed date. But in my case I need to get what is stored in JSON honestly.

Is there any way for RestSharp to disable auto applying UTC offset for date fields in JSON?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's just a local representation of date. The date is the same.

Comment: If you get the UTC date of ""04/22/2016 03:00:00" you will probably end up with the correct version again

Comment: It isn't automatically giving you the UTC date, the *+0000* part idicates that the date is UTC

Comment: It is giving you the UTC time (JSON) coverted to you local timezone (UTC +3 ) Moscow

Comment: Vote to close; no code shown for the `Date` object. We can't fix invisible bugs.

Comment: How do you get `"04/22/2016 03:00:00"`? If this is the output of `DateTime.ToString()`, try `DateTime.ToUniversalTime().ToString()` instead. The value of the instance is likely correct, the way you're using it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

RestSharp will likely use the .Net DateTime methods to parse the string into a DateTime type. The DateTime.Parse method will convert the input string into the timezone read from Regional and Language options from the Control Panel. If you don't want that to happen, the Parse function should be supplied with a different Culture setting (e.g. InvariantCulture). If you don't have control over the RestSharp code, you could set a thread culture before calling the RestSharp method, use System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture. This won't work if RestSharp runs on a different thread. In that case you could convert the input string by doing your own DateTime conversion negating the local machine timezone difference. Then you can then convert it to the proper string format again and use that as input to RestSharp.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the UTC JSON `DateTime` string `"2016-04-22T00:00:00.000+0000"` gets converted to a local `DateTime` object `"04/22/2016 03:00:00"`.

One way out is to specify the `DateTimeKind` for each of you `DateTime` objects as `Local` and then convert them back to `UTC`. See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.datetime.specifykind(v=vs.110).aspx):

The better way out is to use [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) for serialization, under the hood. I have used it liked this:

```
private class MyWrappedRestClient : RestClient
{
    public MyWrappedRestClient(string baseUrl) : base(baseUrl) { }

    private IRestResponse<T> Deserialize<T>(IRestRequest request, IRestResponse rawResponse)
    {
        request.OnBeforeDeserialization(rawResponse);
        var restResponse = (IRestResponse<T>)new RestResponse<T>();
        try
        {
            restResponse = rawResponse.ToAsyncResponse<T>();
            restResponse.Request = request;
            if (restResponse.ErrorException == null)
            {
                restResponse.Data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(restResponse.Content);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            restResponse.ResponseStatus = ResponseStatus.Error;
            restResponse.ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
            restResponse.ErrorException = ex;
        }
        return restResponse;
    }

    public override IRestResponse<T> Execute<T>(IRestRequest request)
    {
        return Deserialize<T>(request, Execute(request));
    }
}
```